# Is that possible to create a class instance with webpart GET values

Tags: f#, get, suave

I created a "Game" class and i'm trying to use values from my webpart path to create an instance of it.

My instance need a playerName so i tried to create one with the name value

```
let g:game.Game = new game.Game()

let php =
request (fun r ->
    match r.queryParam "playerName" with
    | Choice1Of2 name ->  new game.Game(1,name,"hyy")//OK (sprintf "playerName: %s" name)
    | Choice2Of2 msg -> BAD_REQUEST msg)

let webPart = 
choose [
    path "/" >=> (OK "Home")
    path "/elm/api/create.php" >=> php
    ]
startWebServer defaultConfig webPart
```

but it doesn't work because this expression is supposed to be HttpContext type and not Game type.

I'd like to create an instance and call class's methods depending on my path values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first: you cant return 2 different types from your function

```
let php =
    request (fun r ->
        match r.queryParam "playerName" with
        | Choice1Of2 name ->  new game.Game(1,name,"hyy")
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
                              //should probably be a OK 
        //OK (sprintf "playerName: %s" name)
        | Choice2Of2 msg -> BAD_REQUEST msg)
```

Then you also should Jsonify your `Game` object. So probably your code should look somehow like this

```
| Choice1Of2 name ->  
      new game.Game(1,name,"hyy")
      |> toJson
      |> OK
```

please substitute `toJson` with a call of your chosen Json library

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i added Newtonsoft and try it but i got an incompatibility of type on the "OK" because it's waiting for a byte[] and i'm giving a string

Comment: then convert the string into a byte[] ;-)